# Want to branch from my private repo and push a different program to this branch

Tags: git, github

I currently have a private repo with the url of https://github.com/my-name/Pain.git

I pushed the current version and have another, different version in a different folder.  I want to branch off of this repo above and push this other folder as branch "Stress".  I opened my folder and did

```
git init
```

and then

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/my-name/Pain.git
```

then I was assuming i'd be in the repo at the master branch, but when i do

```
git branch
```

I get nothing, and when i try to create a new branch to push this new folder to, I get this:

```
git branch Stress
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'.
```

How do I simply go to the already created repo, create a new branch, and then push my alternate version to that new branch without interfering with the master?

Comment: Running `git init` in a new, empty folder creates a new, empty Git repository. Being empty, this repository *has no commits*. It therefore *has no branches either*, because a branch name must contain the hash ID of some valid, existing commit. Nonetheless, in this empty repository, you're *on* some branch. You're just on a branch that doesn't exist. You can change which nonexistent branch you're on, but until you create a first *commit* you can't actually have any branches. So you really don't want to `git init` a new *repository* in the first place.

Comment: (Based on the question itself, you probably have the wrong mental model of branches in Git. **This is normal!** The way Git actually does branches is *weird*. If you had the right mental model to start with, you might be a mathematician.  In Git, branches—or more precisely, branch names—do not really matter: all that matters are the *commits*. The names are just a method for finding the commits.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this;

```
git checkout -b Stress
```

this code creates a branch named stress and activates that branch